# Initializing variable from a properties file Spring 4.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

am a newbie on Spring 4.0

I want to read from my properties file using annotations @Value

Following is the properties file placed at D:/GmlcConfig.propertise

```
gmlccount=10
```

My Web Config.java is as following

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.nextnav.lcs" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(initMethod = "init",  destroyMethod = "cleanUp")
    public AutoInitalizer myAutoInitalizer(){
        return new AutoInitalizer();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties(){
      PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
      return ppc;
    }


}
```

and in Autoinitalizer i do have a variable which access the value from a property file.

Code for the AutoInitializer is as following:

```
@Component
@Configuration
@PropertySource("File:D:/GmlcConf.propertise")
public class AutoInitalizer {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("loggingService")
    private LoggingServiceImpl loggingService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mGmlc")
    private GmlcConfigDi mGmlc;

    @Value("${gmlccount}")
    private String numConfGmlcCount;


    public void init(){

        loggingService.logInfo(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "Application initalized");
        loggingService.logInfo(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + numConfGmlcCount);
     }
}
```

Am Not Getting the value of numConfGmlcCount in the logs it empty.

Am Getting the Following Exception

```
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
[INFO ] 2015-07-31 09:54:26.159 [localhost-startStop-1] DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
[INFO ] 2015-07-31 09:54:26.165 [localhost-startStop-1] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Jul 31 09:54:26 I
[INFO ] 2015-07-31 09:54:26.197 [localhost-startStop-1] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class com.nextnav.lcs.config.WebConfig]
[INFO ] 2015-07-31 09:54:26.407 [localhost-startStop-1] AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
[WARN ] 2015-07-31 09:54:26.461 [localhost-startStop-1] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autoInitalizer': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.facto
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:326) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658) [spring-webmvc-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530) [spring-webmvc-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484) [spring-webmvc-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [?:1.7.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.nextnav.lcs.AutoInitalizer.numConfGmlcCount; nested exception is java.lang.Il
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:542) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.ja
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gmlccount' in string value "${gmlccount}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:259) ~[spring-beans-4.1.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:800) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:917) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.ja
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4
        ... 26 more
[ERROR] 2015-07-31 09:54:26.479 [localhost-startStop-1] DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autoInitalizer': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.facto
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:326) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484) [spring-webmvc-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar:7.0.47]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [?:1.7.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.nextnav.lcs.AutoInitalizer.numConfGmlcCount; nested exception is java.lang.Il
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:542) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.ja
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gmlccount' in string value "${gmlccount}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:259) ~[spring-beans-4.1.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:800) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:917) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.ja
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4
        ... 26 more
Jul 31, 2015 9:54:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autoInitalizer': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.facto
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.nextnav.lcs.AutoInitalizer.numConfGmlcCount; nested exception is java.lang.Il
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gmlccount' in string value "${gmlccount}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:259)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:800)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:917)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
        ... 28 more

Jul 31, 2015 9:54:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /LCSCLIENT threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gmlccount' in string value "${gmlccount}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:259)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:800)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:917)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: GmlcConfig.propertise, shouldn't it be GmlcConfig.properties ?

Comment: Please share your application context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import your property file like as ("file:D:/GmlcConf.properties").

and autowired

private Environment env;

in your class.

Read property file as bellow:

env.getProperty("pass Key of propertyvalue");
e.g.
if name = abc
in property file get as:

env.getProperty(name)

happy coding...

Comment: Didn't worked problem is in parsing the config file not in reading

Comment: there should no space in  propertiy's value of file, please check property file.

Comment: Properties file is fine

Answer (score 3):

Add this configuration on application-context.xml and put properties file in classpath location.

```
<beans:bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="appProperties" />
</beans:bean>

<bean id="appProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="singleton" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
           <value>classpath:GmlcConfig.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And where you want the value of property file use this

```
@Autowired
@Value("#{appProperties.gmlccount}")
private String gmlccount;
```

Hope this stuff will work.

Comment: I want through java config